# Using module.exports to return an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using csvtojson to parse a csv file and want to use it in another module in NodeJS.  Pretty sure this is a noob issue in my attempt to learn NodeJS.

```
function loadPortfolio (portfolio) {
  //Converter Class 
  var Converter = require("./node_modules/csvtojson").Converter;
  var converter = new Converter({});

  //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished 
  converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonArray) {
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
    var portfolioObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);

    module.exports = loadPortfolio;
  });

  //read from file 
  require("fs").createReadStream("./charlesriverexport.csv").pipe(converter);

};
```

Then in my app.js file:

```
var loadPortfolio = require('./loadPortfolio');

console.log("Portfolio: ", portfolio);
```

But, unfortunately the portfolio object comes as undefined.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: maybe try ``console.log("Portfolio: ", loadPortfolio);``

Comment: `module.exports` has to be modified synchronously. Node won't wait for an event to occur or try to detect the reassignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exported module has to be a function that takes a callback as its parameter. The exported function will supply the callback with the data that is generated asynchronously.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Converter = require('./node_modules/csvtojson').Converter;

module.exports = function loadPortfolio (callback) {

  var converter = new Converter({});

  fs.createReadStream('./charlesriverexport.csv').pipe(converter);

  converter.on('end_parsed', function (jsonArray) {
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
    var portfolioObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    callback(portfolioObj);
  });

};
```

And in the file where you use this module:

```
var loadPortfolio = require('./loadPortfolio');
loadPortfolio(function(portfolioObj) {
  console.log(typeof portfolioObj); // => 'object'
});
```

Edit: if you want to use the asynchronously fetched `portfolioObj` outside of the callback context of `loadPortfolio` you have to set an undefined variable then assign it within the callback.

```
//set undefined variable
var portfolio;

//import your function
require('./loadPortfolio')(function(portfolioObj) {

  //assign the global variable a value
  portfolio = portfolioObj;

  //when doSomething runs portfolio is guaranteed to be defined
  doSomething();
});

//see the problem with calling doSomething outside the callback?
doSomething(); // => 'undefined'

function doSomething() {
  console.log(typeof portfolio); // => 'object'
}
```

A neater way to do this is with promises, however.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you Daniel, much appreciated!

Comment: @user3736414 if it works properly could you mark it as answered? thank you

Comment: Done.  Interested though in another thing:  when I use the module in app.js, the portfolioObj can only be used within that function 'loadPortfolio'.  I understand this has to do with function scoping in Javascript, but how would I use that object globally?

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the `loadPortfolio()` function anywhere, you're using the wrong variable name in your `app.js` file and your `module.exports` can be moved to improve readability

> The last part is optional but makes it easy to see whats exported at
>   the top of every file as soon as you open it
>
> **NOTE:** This only works if you use named function definitions: `function myFunc() {}` and NOT when you store the function in a variable i.e. `let myFunc = function() {}`.

Hoisting in JS allows to do this in your module file:

```
module.exports = loadPortfolio;
function loadPortfolio (portfolio) {
  //Converter Class 
  var Converter = require("./node_modules/csvtojson").Converter;
  var converter = new Converter({});

  //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished 
  converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonArray) {
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
    var portfolioObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);


  });

  //read from file 
  require("fs").createReadStream("./charlesriverexport.csv").pipe(converter);

};
```

As functions get loaded before the module is executed, you can export before the function is defined.

then you need to call the function in app.js

```
var loadPortfolio = require('./loadPortfolio');
var portfolio = loadPortfolio();

console.log("Portfolio: ", portfolio);
```